# How to show image in first row of Android ListView when loading ListView?

Tags: android, listview

There is a `ListView` and list_row xml which includes `LinearLayout` with background image.The requirement is to show the image in first row of `ListView` when loading data.And subsequently show and hide the image when tap on the rows of `ListView`.

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) ListView.getAdapter().getView(0, null, null);
TableRow selectedRow = (TableRow) vg.getChildAt(0);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) selectedRow.getChildAt(0);
ll.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

I used the above source code and try to do it.But this is not working and does not return any null objects.Show and hide part is working on using `ItemClickListner`.But I need to show the image when loading data.
I try to do it in Adapter class and I was able to show the image.But I couldn't hide it when tap on other rows of `ListView`.How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

For this, I would suggest you to use `ListView.addHeaderView(v)` method. It will allow you to add a view as header of ListView (which will always be on top of other list items). Afterwards, when you've implemented **ItemClickListner**, simply call `ListView.removeHeaderView(v)` to remove that header view from list.